# web.config trouble with rewriting the numeric id as a query_string

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I want a rewrite rule in my `web.config` that will translate the following urls:

```
mypage to mypage.php
mydirectory/mypage to mydirectory/mypage.php
mydir2/mydir1/mypage to mydir2/mydir1/mypage.php
mypage/12345 to mypage.php?id=12345
mydirectory/mypage/12345 to mydirectory/mypage.php?id=12345
mydir2/mydir1/mypage/12345 to mydir2/mydir1/mypage.php?id=12345
```

As a `.htaccess` file in Apache, I simply do this with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?id=$2&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%1 [L]
```

I tried reproducing this behaviour in IIS with a `web.config`. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="hide .php extension without losing ?id=" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php?id={R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But when I go to my browser and type `http://localhost/mydirectory/mypage/12345`, I get a 404 page not found.  I see on the 404 page that request url is `http://localhost:80/mydirectory/mypage/12345` and physical path is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mydirectory\mypage\12345`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait, I figured it out.  I replaced the node `name="hide .php extension without losing ?id="` with

```
<rule name="hide .php extension without losing ?id=" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php?id={R:2}" />
</rule>
```